# Event for finger being moved off button but not lifted in objective C (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events

Is there an event which will get whether the user has moved his finger outside of the button?
Kind of like TouchUpOutside except without the "up" bit.

Like how the iphone keyboard, the letter gets smaller (back to normal) as you move your finger of the letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`UIControlEventTouchDragExit`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW65).  You can attach a target and action to the control for that particular control event.

Comment: Thanks i looked in apples documentqtion and saw that but it seemed the same as UIControlEventTouchDragOutside. What exactly is the difference,

Comment: @Jonathan if you're dragging inside and exit the control, then it's `UIControlEventTouchExit`.  While you're dragging around outside, it's `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`.  When you re-enter the control, it's `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter`.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this but it only fires when the finger gets far enough away. They both do similar things except the Exit only fire once wheras the DragOutside fires multiple times while the finger is moving.